# Unable to download ERA5 land hourly data via Google earth engine platform recently

Tags: google-earth-engine, era5

Recently I find that I can't download ERA5 land hourly data via Google Earth Engine, and the following code can only return null. But if I replace the first row with "var era51 = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')", it could return the images. Is there something wrong with the ERA5 land hourly data?

Here is the code:

```
var era51 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-02-02')
.select('total_precipitation');


function exportImageCollection(imgCol) { 
  var indexList = imgCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ["system:index"]) 
                        .get("list"); 
  indexList.evaluate(function(indexs) { 
    for (var i=0; i<indexs.length; i++) { 
      var image = imgCol.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", indexs[i])).first(); 
      print(image)
    } 
  }); 
} 

exportImageCollection(era51);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Turns out that it was a problem on the Dataset side. It is now fixed. Happy downloading :)

Same problem here, about last week my script worked smoothly, but today it just fails. I use to work with the python API, but I've been able to download Landsat-[5,8] images with no problem.

I tried to use Earth Engine Javascript API to download the same area with both: an URL (`image.GetDownloadURL()`) and to Drive (`Export.image.toDrive()`); but both approaches also failed.

Tests in Javascript API:

```
var imgcol = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY");
var subset = imgcol.filterDate("2010-09-11T10", "2010-09-11T11").filterBounds(geometry);
var img = subset.map(function(x){return x.clip(geometry);}).first();

Map.addLayer(subset.select("surface_latent_heat_flux"))

var url = img.getDownloadURL(
      { 
      name: 'single_band',
      bands: ['surface_latent_heat_flux'],
      region: geometry
    } 
  );  
  
print(url); //url is printed but fails in the download

Export.image.toDrive(
  {
    image: img,
    description: 'LET',
    folder: 'ee_test',
    region: geometry,
    scale: 9000
});
```

Could it be an error in Earth Engine end?

EDIT: Turns out that it was a problem on the Dataset side. It is now fixed. Happy downloading :)